# Checking Content-Type of HTTP POST Request to Java servlet

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I've written a simple servlet that accepts HTTP POST requests and sends back a short response.  Here's the code for the servlet:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class MapleTAServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Receives XML request text containing grade data and returns     response in XML", urlPatterns = { "/MapleTAServlet" })
public class MapleTAServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MapleTAServlet.class);

   /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {       
        String strXMLResponse = "<Response><code>";
        String strMessage = "";
        int intCode = 0;
        ServletOutputStream stream = null;
        BufferedInputStream buffer = null;

    try
    {   
        String strContentType = request.getContentType();   

        // Make sure that the incoming request is XML data, otherwise throw up a red flag
        if (strContentType != "text/xml")
        {
            strMessage = "Incorrect MIME type";
        }
        else
        {
            intCode = 1;        
        } // end if

        strXMLResponse += intCode + "</code><message>" + strMessage + "</message></Response>";

        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.setContentLength(strXMLResponse.length());

        int intReadBytes = 0;

        stream = response.getOutputStream();

        // Converts the XML string to an input stream of a byte array
        ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(strXMLResponse.getBytes());
        buffer = new BufferedInputStream(bs);

        while ((intReadBytes = buffer.read()) != -1)
        {
            stream.write(intReadBytes);
        } // end while
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally 
    {
        stream.close();
        buffer.close();
    } // end try-catch

    }

}
```

And here's the client that I'm using to send the request:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.*;

public class TestClient 
{

   /**
    * @param args
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BufferedReader inStream = null;

        try
            {
        // Connect to servlet
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/mapleta/mtaservlet");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Initialize the connection 
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        //conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.connect();

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

        inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String strXMLRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Request></Request>";
        out.write(strXMLRequest.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        String strServerResponse = "";

        System.out.println("Server says: ");
        while ((strServerResponse = inStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(strServerResponse);
        } // end while

        inStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // end try catch
     }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that when I run the client program, I'm getting the following output:

```
Server says: 
<Response><code>0</code><message>Incorrect MIME type</message></Response>
```

I've tried calling request.getContentType() and have gotten "text/xml" as the output.  Just trying to figure out why the string isn't matching up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're comparing strings the wrong way.

```
if (strContentType != "text/xml")
```

[Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are not [primitives](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), they are [objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). When using `!=` to compare two objects, it will only test if they do not point to the same **reference**. However, you're rather interested in comparing the **content** of two different string references, not if they point to the same reference.

You should then use [the `equals()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) for this:

```
if (!strContentType.equals("text/xml"))
```

Or, better, to avoid `NullPointerException` if the `Content-Type` header is not present (and thus becomes `null`):

```
if (!"text/xml".equals(strContentType))
```

Comment: is is this the right way to determine the contenttype of an HttpServletRequest? I'm not that satisfied with it because when you look for exact string matches "text/xml" is different than "text/xml;charset=UTF-8" and thats different from "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" and thats different from "application/xml". so is there a way to cleanly just differ e.g. xml requests from form requests? so without covering manually all the varieties of strings that can represent different request types

Comment: I got a CAST violation on my doPost method for not calling getContentType method inside...can i use it simply his way try {
   String msg="";
   String strContentType = req.getContentType();
   if (!"text/xml".equals(strContentType))
    msg="Invalid MIME type";
   }catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: how it behaves if getContentType returns null