# How to detect attachments in MS Office files, in a java context.?

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, exe, attachment

I am having a web application and we are implementing an upload document feature. We have implemented some content filtering logic based on the File Magic Number and AntiVirus checks are implemented based on ClamAV/libclamav.jar API. We are thinking of having a check for MS Office files having attachments. How can we do list/detect the attachments in an MS Office files MSWord/Excel/Ppt using JAVA. ?

Comment: check out Apache POI - the Java API for Microsoft Documents https://poi.apache.org

Answer (score 0):

http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php has a comprehensive list of media types for MS office file extensions. You can check for the Content-Type header to inspect the incoming attachment's media type. See [Checking Content-Type of HTTP POST Request to Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663457/checking-content-type-of-http-post-request-to-java-servlet) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. We need to find out NOT the type of file being attached using the upload doc API, the next level, ie internal attachments present in the MS Word file.